# Fill fields with geolocation coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I am trying to fill two fields with the result of a geolocation query. This is one of the first javascripts I have written.

Here is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/aGupn/2/

```
$(function (getLocation) {

    var Geo = {};

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }

    //Get the latitude and the longitude;
    function success(position) {
        Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        populateHeader(Geo.lat, Geo.lng);
    }

    function error() {
        console.log("Geocoder failed");
    }

    function populateHeader(lat, lng) {
        $('#lat').html(lat);
        $('#lng').html(lng);
    }

});
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using `input.html(...)` instead of `input.val(...)`. `input.html(...)` sets the `innerHTML` property of an element. However, that's not how you set the value of input element. You want to set the `value` attribute/property, therefore use `input.val(...)`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aGupn/3/)

```
$('#lat').val(lat);
$('#lng').val(lng);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It works! I have only one question though, it seems to automatically populate the fields when I visit the page every time, instead of waiting for me to push the button. Are you able to see why this is happening?

Comment: @Jimmy Yes, it's because the `$` function execute the function passed as argument as soon as the document is ready.

Comment: If I remove the $ it doesnt function. I only want it to execute when the button is clicked called Get coordinates

Comment: It's not respecting best practices since everything is global, however it's only for the example, have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/aGupn/6/